# How to make tkinter draw a new set of labels and entries after I change the data that said labels and entries are based upon?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to write a simple program that will allow the user to input data into entry brackets and generate text. It is possible that the number of brackets will change, hence I created two buttons that update the list, on which a "for" loop creates entry and label brackets. I've tried many attempts, but no matter how I write functions, it looks like the new brackets are drawn upon the previous one. They also do not refresh, meaning if list_1 contains 7 elements and list_2 - 5 after using lst_2 some of the brackets from lst_1 remain.

I tried multiple attempts to write different functions, but I just can't make it work. It always looks the same in GUI.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import re
import pyperclip
import textwrap
from tkmacosx import Button
from tkinter import ttk
import random

window=tk.Tk()
window.title("Myszkoprogram, ver 1.2")
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(master=window)
tab_control.grid(row=0, column=0)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(master=tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(master=tab_control)

def validate_input(text):
    return re.match("^[0-9,]*$", text) is not None

vcmd = (window.register(validate_input), "%P")

dash = '\u2013'

opis_przycisku_2 = textwrap.fill("Usuń zawartość komórek", width=20)

tab_control.add(tab1, text = "Morfologia i biochemia")
tab_control.add(tab2, text = "Bilans płynów")

liczba_drenow=1
lst_bilans_1 = ["Płyny dożylne", "Płyny doustne", "Sonda", "Dreny", "Mocz"]
lst_bilans_2 = ["PFFFF", "DADAWDW", "Sonda", "L", "P", "Mocz", "MALAKAKAKAAA", "BLAAAAH"]
lst_bilans=lst_bilans_1

lst_bilans_unit="ml"
lst_words_for_bilans=["zanotowano", "wpisano", "zapisano", "napisano"]

frm_bilans_part = tk.Frame(master=tab2)
frm_bilans_part.grid(row=0, column=0)

frm_full_data_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_bilans_part)
frm_full_data_bilans.grid(row=0, column=0)

frm_btn_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_bilans_part)
frm_btn_bilans.grid(row=0, column=1)

frm_text_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_bilans_part)
frm_text_bilans.grid(row=0, column=2)

lbl_info_bilans = tk.Label(master=frm_full_data_bilans, text="Bilans płynów:")
lbl_info_bilans.grid(row=0, column=0)

frm_ent_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_full_data_bilans)
frm_ent_bilans.grid(row=1, column=0)

entry_list_bilans=[]
def paint_entry():
    for idx, value in enumerate(lst_bilans):
        lbl_bilans=tk.Label(master=frm_ent_bilans, text=value + ":")
        lbl_bilans.grid(row=idx, column=0)
        ent_bilans=tk.Entry(master=frm_ent_bilans, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
        ent_bilans.grid(row=idx, column=1)
        entry_list_bilans.append(ent_bilans)
paint_entry()




def create_bilans():
    data_bilans = str()
    values = [ent.get() for ent in entry_list_bilans]
    for idx, value in enumerate(values):
        if value == "":
            continue
        else:
            data_bilans = data_bilans + lst_bilans[idx] + " {0} " + value + " " + lst_bilans_unit + ", "
    if data_bilans:
            data_bilans = "W bilansie wodnym {1}: " + data_bilans[:len(data_bilans)-2] + "."
    else:
        data_bilans = str()
    random_word = random.choice(lst_words_for_bilans)
    variables_for_data_bilans = [dash, random_word]
    data_bilans = data_bilans.format(*variables_for_data_bilans)
    pyperclip.copy(data_bilans)
    wrapped_data_bilans = textwrap.fill(data_bilans, width=75)
    lbl_text_bilans["text"] = wrapped_data_bilans

def remove_text_bilans():
    for ent in entry_list_bilans:
        ent.delete(0, tk.END)

def change_dren_number_to_1():
    frm_ent_bilans.destroy()
    frm_ent_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_full_data_bilans)
    lst_bilans=lst_bilans_1
    for idx, value in enumerate(lst_bilans):
        lbl_bilans=tk.Label(master=frm_ent_bilans, text=value + ":")
        lbl_bilans.grid(row=idx, column=0)
        ent_bilans=tk.Entry(master=frm_ent_bilans, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
        ent_bilans.grid(row=idx, column=1)
        entry_list_bilans.append(ent_bilans)

def change_dren_number_to_2():
    frm_ent_bilans.destroy()
    frm_ent_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_full_data_bilans)
    lst_bilans=lst_bilans_2
    for idx, value in enumerate(lst_bilans):
        lbl_bilans=tk.Label(master=frm_ent_bilans, text=value + ":")
        lbl_bilans.grid(row=idx, column=0)
        ent_bilans=tk.Entry(master=frm_ent_bilans, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
        ent_bilans.grid(row=idx, column=1)
        entry_list_bilans.append(ent_bilans)
 

frm_funct_btn_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_btn_bilans)
frm_funct_btn_bilans.grid(row=1, column=0)

frm_number_of_dren_bilans = tk.Frame(master=frm_btn_bilans)
frm_number_of_dren_bilans.grid(row=0, column=0)


opis_przycisku_1_bilans = textwrap.fill("Utwórz tekst i skopiuj do schowka", width=20)
text_convert_bilans = Button(master = frm_funct_btn_bilans,
                      text= opis_przycisku_1_bilans,
                      command = create_bilans,
                      bg='#ADEFD1',
                      fg='#00203F',
                      borderless=1,
                      width=150)
text_convert_bilans.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=80)

btn_remove_bilans = Button(master=frm_funct_btn_bilans,
                    text = opis_przycisku_2,
                    command = remove_text_bilans,
                    bg='#E69A8D', fg='#5F4B8B',
                    borderless=1,
                    width=150,
                    activebackground=('#AE0E36', '#D32E5E'),
                    activeforeground='#E69A8D')
btn_remove_bilans.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=80)

opis_przycisku_3_bilans = textwrap.fill(("Liczba drenów {0} 2").format(dash))
btn_change_dren_to_2 = Button(master=frm_number_of_dren_bilans,
                              text = opis_przycisku_3_bilans,
                              command = change_dren_number_to_2)
btn_change_dren_to_2.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=80)

opis_przycisku_4_bilans = textwrap.fill(("Liczba drenów {0} 1").format(dash))
btn_change_dren_to_1 = Button(master=frm_number_of_dren_bilans,
                              text = opis_przycisku_4_bilans,
                              command = change_dren_number_to_1)
btn_change_dren_to_1.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=80)

lbl_text_bilans = tk.Label(master=frm_text_bilans, width=55)
lbl_text_bilans.grid(row=0, column=0)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mre] so it's easier for us to see what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'frm_ent_bilans' referenced before assignment` raised when either `change_dren_number_to_1()` or `change_dren_number_to_2()` is executed.  Actually you can just remove all the widgets inside `frm_ent_bilans` instead of destroying and recreating the frame.

Comment: See [ask]. Just focus on a specific implementation. Don't say "no matter how", "multiple attempts", etc. Also do a preliminary debugging.